# Checking Body width

Tags: weight-gain, body-measurements

Recently I was shown changes in my pant size from last year of same month and the width was like half of finger size wider from what was last year. I do have tummy but it got me thinking as I use to work a lot last year. Can it be width of body frame being broaden or really my waist that is showing this? I also use to eat like 8 meals a day last year.

Answer (score 1):

Simply record your natural waist, hips, and umbilicus circumferences along with your sagittal abdominal diameter each month, and graph the data.

[image: sagittal abdominal diameter]

Comment: It's confusing on where one should measure the waist because at naval button or below it because usual my pants is below naval button.

Comment: Hence my comment to measure natural (minimum), umbilicus (at the belly button), and hips.